# LARAVEL application with NGINX server showing 404 error in windows

Tags: windows, nginx, php-7.4, laravel-6.2

I am new to PHP and Laravel.I have cloned a laravel project from git and save my local directory
`"C:\Projects\TestProject\public"`.

```
NGINX folder C:\nginx
php folder C:\PHP
```

My NGINX Config is as below

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;
   root     C:/Projects/TestProject/public;

location / {
   
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     index index.html index.htm  index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9999;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I have also installed composer and necessary dependecies.But when i try to access `http://localhost/TestProject/public/index.php`its showing `404` and showing `No input file specified.`

I have created a sample php file Test.php with `phpinfo()` int the same folder root.When i acces `http://localhost/TestProject/public/Test.php` it is displaying the PHP information on browser but the network shows 404 for the url. My PHP version is 7.4.

Comment: You should run `php-cgi.exe` and make sure it is listening on port 9999

Comment: Yes.Iam running >php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9999

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the params' file in the configuration block:

```
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Then the final block should be:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9999;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```